# Count Arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays, count

I'm trying to count the repetitions have a key [number]

My return

```
[result] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [duration] => 6
            )

        [codes] => Array
        (
        [number] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [numberCode] => 1006
                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [numberCode] => 0047
                            )

                    )
            )   
        )
    )   

[1] => Array
    (
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [duration] => 8
        )
    [codes] => Array
        (
            [number] => Array
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [numberCode] => 0001
                        )
                )
        )
    )
)
```

It does not show the total number of repetitions, but the values ​​within the array.

The expected result:

loop 1: number = 2

loop 2: number = 1

Attempts to use count, sizeof, but do not show a number of arrays [], only the total fields within [number].

The return is an XML turned array

Comment: What is your expected result ?

Comment: The expected result:

loop 1: number = 2 <br>

loop 2: number = 1

Comment: This looks as though it's an encoded XML document, which could be easily queried using XPath.

Comment: Your example suggest the `$array` value is string of `var_dump` - can you please share valid example input?

Comment: does that have to be your array format? Seems it would be a lot easier with standard array syntax?

Comment: @treyBake edited the return to understand better.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to loop through the array and increment the counter every time you 
you encounter the number key

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($array['result'] as $subArray) {
    if(isset($subArray['number'])) {
        $counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't work - as you not counting the right field (where the 'codes' keys?)

Answer (score 0):

This will print the total number loop and total numbercode count.

```
$output = array();
foreach($array('result') as $item){
    $childOutput = array();
    if(is_array($item)) {
        // get total loop
        $childOutput['numberLoop'] = count($item);
        $numberCode = 0;
        foreach($item['number'] as $sub_item) {
            // get number code
            if(isset($sub_item['@attributes']['numberCode'])) {
                $numberCode = $numberCode + 1;
            }
        }

        $childOutput['numberCode'] = $numberCode;

        $output[] = $childOutput;
    }


}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
echo '</pre>';
```